# URL not matching url pattern in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I'm trying to learn Django, went through the official tutorial and giving it a try on my own. I've created a new app and can access the index page but I can't use pattern matching to go to any other page. Here is my `monthlyreport/url.py`

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

#app_name = 'monthlyreport'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

and my `monthlyreport/views`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views import generic

from .models import Report

def index(request):
    report_list = Report.objects.all()[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('monthlyreport/index.html')
    context = {
        'report_list': report_list,
    } 
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
    
def detail(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at question %s." % question_id)
```

The debug for http://127.0.0.1:8000/monthlyreport/0 is showing

```
 Using the URLconf defined in maxhelp.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
 
 monthlyreport [name='index']
 monthlyreport <int:question_id>/ [name='detail']
 polls/
 admin/
 accounts/

 The current path, monthlyreport/0, didn’t match any of these.
```

Again, using http://127.0.0.1:8000/monthlyreport/ to go to index works fine, but I cant match the integer. I would really appreciate any suggestions, I am very, very confused at this point.

Comment: can you show us your root urls.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your code is of one `slash(/)`. In your root `urls.py` file, from where you must have used something like:

```
path('monthlyreport', include('monthlyreport.url'))
```

So, the problem here is that you should have ending `/` in your path if you are setting your urls in *monthlyreport.url* like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

Or else, you have to put `slash(/)` infront of every new path like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('/<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
          |
          |
          V
        Here
]
```

#### Solution

In summary, convinient solution is adding  `slash(/)` after path in urls.py file. Like:

```
path('monthlyreport/', include('monthlyreport.url'))
                   |
                   |
                   |
                   V
             Add slash here
```

Comment: If I could buy you a drink I would, I've been beating my head against this for hours. Thanks!

Comment: @Nate My pleasure.... Always focus on the error messages, they have all the information about the problem :)

Comment: thanks, this just saved me a bunch of debugging time!